# Period of a product of $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

I want to find the period of $\sin(t) \cos(\pi t)$.

I started off by transforming that into
$\frac{1}{2}\left [ \sin((\pi +1)t) - \sin((\pi - 1)t\right ]$, but then I get stuck.  How do I find the least common multiple of $\pi + 1$ and $\pi - 1$? Is that what I need to do to find the period of the whole thing?

Comment: There is no nonzero common multiple of $\pi-1$ and $\pi+1$. By the way, what makes you think this function is periodic?

Comment: Seeing as $\pi$ and $1$ are independent over the rationals, I doubt that this function is periodic.

Comment: So then the function $\sin(2t)cos(2\pi t)$ is not periodic?  It has no period?

Comment: @stackedAE: Finally typed out a proof that your function is not periodic.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function

Comment: I posted an answer below that gives a very short proof of what some people here are _asserting_, and involves no trigonometry.  (Provided, however, that you believe that $\pi$ is irrational, which takes some work to prove.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We show that $\sin(t)\cos(\pi t)$ is *not* periodic. Suppose to the contrary that it is periodic. Let $f(t)=|\sin(t)\cos(\pi t)|$. Then $f(t)$ is periodic. Let $p$ be a period of $f(t)$.

Let $m$ be the maximum value of $f(t)$ in the interval $[0,p]$.  If $f(t)$ is periodic, then $m$ is the maximum value of $f(t)$ as $t$ ranges over *all* the reals.  We will show that this is not the case, by showing that there is a $t$ such that $f(t)>m$.

Note first that $m\ne 1$. For if  $f(t)$ ever takes on the value  $1$, then   $|\sin(t)|$ and $|\cos(\pi t)|$ must be  simultaneously equal to $1$. So $t$ is  an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, say $t=q \pi/2$. Also, $\pi t$ is a multiple of $\pi$, so $t$ is an integer. It follows that  $\pi=2t/q$. This is impossible, since $\pi$ is irrational.

We now show that there is a $t$ such that $f(t)>m$.  This is easy, but uses some machinery.

The sequence $(\sin(n))$ is *dense* in the interval $[-1,1]$.  Thus there is an integer $t$ such that $\sin(t)>m$.  Since $|\cos(\pi n)|=1$, it follows that $f(t) >m$.

**Comment:** A quick search shows that there are many proofs of the fact that the sequence $(\sin(n))$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. Indeed the problem has been posed and solved on MSE. The most intuitive argument shows that the points $(\cos(n), \sin(n))$ are dense on the unit circle. The result for $(\sin(n))$ then follows by projecting on the $y$-axis. In general, if $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, then the points $(\cos(n\theta), \sin(n\theta))$ are dense on the unit circle.

Comment: Nice. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Didier Piau: But not as nice as dozens of yours.

Comment: $\langle$ *Blushes* $\rangle$.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a more self-contained proof that $f(t) = \sin(t) \cos(\pi t)$ is not periodic, using only the fact that $\pi$ is irrational.  If    $f(t)$ had period $p$, then we'd also have $f(p) = f(0) = 0$.  Now this implies
either $\sin(p) = 0$, i.e. $p = n \pi$ for some nonzero integer $n$, or $\cos(\pi p) = 0$, i.e.
$p = n+1/2$ for some integer $n$.  But 
$$f(1/2 + n \pi) - f(1/2) = (-1)^{n+1} \sin(1/2) \sin(n \pi^2) \ne 0$$ since neither $1/2$ nor $n \pi^2$ is  an integer multiple of $\pi$ (if it were $m \pi$, then $\pi = m/n$ would be rational).
Similarly, 
$$f(\pi + (n+1/2)) - f(\pi)= (-1)^n \sin(\pi^2) \sin(n+1/2) \ne 0$$ since neither $\pi^2$ nor $n+1/2$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Nice solution. But $f(\pi/2)\ne0$, hence I guess one should use $\pi$ instead of $\pi/2$ to disqualify $p=n+1/2$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of correcting this answer to meet Didier's objection. (I had to do this so I could upvote it...)

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks. Upvoting too, then.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is a common multiple $p$ of $\pi+1$ and $\pi-1$.  Then
$$
\begin{align}
p & = n(\pi+1) \\
p & = m(\pi-1)
\end{align}
$$

(**Later note:** The context of the problem should make it clear that this means $n$ and $m$ are positive integers.)

It follows via a bit of algebra that
$$
\pi=\frac{n+m}{n-m}.
$$
Therefore $\pi$ is rational.  But in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_pi_is_irrational) it is proved that $\pi$ is irrational.  At least two of the proofs given there can be understood by someone who knows nothing beyond first-year calculus.

The function is therefore not periodic, but it is [almost periodic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function).

Comment: you probably mean a «common non-zero integer multiple» or something, but both $0$ and $(\pi+1)(\pi-1)$ are surely common multiples :)

Comment: I meant "multiple" in the sense that makes sense in the context of the problem.

Comment: @mariano: I was pretty heavily abused for making this joke earlier http://math.stackexchange.com/a/74730/18005 ('integer' has since been edited into the title).

Comment: @opt: in that case, you used a *whole answer* to make the joke, and did not take the chance to actually —well...— answer the question!